# How to retrieve large data from Oracle database using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

I am trying to retrieve a large amount of data from an Oracle database in .NET.
I am using a .NET [`DBDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx) which is working fine with small amount of data but when the data become medium or large it stops functioning and I have no idea why. 
How can i retrieve large amount of data?

Comment: *it stop from functioning* is not a problem description that a software developer should use in his vocabulary. Those sort of phrases are more adapted to users who don't know or care how a computer works. A software developer should explain what he is trying to do, what he has tried so far by showing his code, explain the expected results, the actual results and how they differ. In case of exception he should post the full exception details, etc... I think you get the point.

Comment: Do you use System.Data.OracleClient or Oracle.DataAccess.Client?

Comment: @Darin - that comment is more powerful than a slap actually!

Comment: @Pabuc, I just ask for details because I don't have telepathic skills to read other people's minds and try to explain how questions should be asked here if one expected to get helpful answers.

Comment: yes i do use System.Data.OracleClient

Comment: thank you for your comment :) ... i can use all the help that i can get :)

Comment: @Darin - I know, that is why I voted +1 for your comment. I hate when I see a question with no code or not enough information. We ain't no superman!

Comment: @Mohamed: Just exactly how much data are we talking?  In a comment you said the data types were TEXT and BINARY.  Is your query possibly timing out in .net?

Comment: If you need unregistered accounts merged, please flag this for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html). That is Oracle Data Provider written for .NET and it's much better optimized for communication with Oracle databases.

Microsoft deprecated Oracle Client (System.Data.OracleClient) (http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx) and advised to use 3rd hand tools.

**EDITED:**

Maby you should take a look at this similar question and answer: [Big Performance Problems With Oracle DataReader in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141175/big-performance-problems-with-oracle-datareader-in-net)

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you give me a reliable information source for it. its a critical task i must do in short amount of time :)

Comment: What do you consider by "medium or large" amount of that? What amount are we talking about?

Comment: @Mohamed if you expect helpful answers you could show your code and the exact exception message you are getting.

Comment: well more than 20 records is considered medium.

Comment: it just return empty no exception msg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you are expecting answers related to your question with very little information, answering these would help ***OTHERS*** to answer your question:

1- What is your data type in database

2- How are you trying to fetch the data (Some code would help a lot)

3- Are there any indexes, how big is the table and how complex is your query, have you tried optimizing it? Try writing your query.

...

---

Ok, here is what you can try and tell us if it changed anything...

```
static void DownloadBlob(OracleConnection myConnection)
{
  OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM table", myConnection);
  myConnection.Open();
  OracleDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);
  try
  {
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
      //Obtain OracleLob directly from OracleDataReader
      OracleLob myLob = myReader.GetOracleLob(myReader.GetOrdinal("Ordinal"));
      if (!myLob.IsNull)
      {
        // I hope it is BLOB :)
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    myReader.Close();
    myConnection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: the datatype is text and binarydata.

Comment: i wish i could put some code but my company prevent me of doing so. i can only put the idea i am really sorry. the table is very big more than 1000 record my query is straight forward select from the oracle database.

Comment: have you tried running the sql query directly from oracle? Are you still getting 0 results? You shouldn't, it should take a long time to execute if you have loads of data. If it is executing fine in oracle but slow in .net, that would help others..

Comment: when i run it in oracle it show the result. i am just thinking but would it be better if i retrieve the data in xml files ? and is it possible?

Comment: What data types do you use? RAW, LONG RAW?

Comment: @Mohamed: adding yet another technology, especially one known for hurting performance, is not a good idea.